# Can server.max-write-idle be set as 0 for lighthttpd and what does it mean?

Tags: lighttpd

We need to disable the server.max-write-idle feature of lighthttpd, can it be achieved with being set as 0?

Answer (score 0):

Setting server.max-write-idle = 0 **will not** do what you want.  It will result in connections being aborted very quickly if the response is not immediately available and fits in kernel socket buffers.

server.max-write-idle = 65535 is the maximum value, which is over 18 hours.  Will that work for your use?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So, it seems we have to customize the source code of lighthttpd to implement this requirement.